# Macbook Pro Wi-Fi problems after Yosemite 10.10.5 update

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, wifi

I've had my Macbook Pro for about a year now. It is a late 2013 Retina model running Yosemite. Until a few days ago, its Wi-Fi worked fine. However, after the 10.10.5 update, its Wi-Fi has become very slow and drops packets unless I'm a foot away from my wifi router. When I'm in my usual location of the next room, ping times go up to hundreds of milliseconds.

```
shanglin$ ping 192.168.1.1  
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1): 56 data bytes  
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0  
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=944.501 ms  
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=325.487 ms  
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=78.760 ms  
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=126.286 ms  
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5  
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=41.813 ms  
^C  
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---  
8 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 37.5% packet loss  
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 41.813/303.369/944.501/335.189 ms
```

None of the other devices on my Wi-Fi network are having a problem. I've tried removing plist files from SystemConfiguration, and I've turned off Bluetooth.

My Wi-Fi router is a Cisco E1200 running 802.11n on the 2.4GHz band. I don't think it can run on the 5GHz band. I've tried updating the router's firmware to the latest, but it has not helped.

Any suggestions that could help?

Comment: I have the same problem. After the update to Yosemite 10.10.5 the WiFi network does not work properly. With previous versions it was a little slow, but now the WiFi network is almost totally out. It's not a problem in the router, it's a problem with the software running in the mac itself. The problem goes even worst if you turn on the Bluetooth to use a mouse or a keyboard (this happens to me). If you delete all WiFi connections and then map your router again, for a few minutes is gonna work fine, but then the problem appears again. I just wonder why I spent almost 3000€ in a macBook Pro lapto

Comment: Tonight my wifi seems to be working significantly better, but I haven't changed anything. Strange!

Comment: I have the same problem. I felt very lucky when everybody had a problem but me. But since the update to 10.10.5 my wifi drives me crazy. It's very unstable and until now I couldn't find a way to get it fixed. My hope lies on El Capitan. I'm almost willing to install the Beta. This is very annoying.

Comment: I have the same problem with my 5 year old Macbook Pro. Upgraded to 10.10.5. No problems, then the wifi went slow. Tried several fixes, they worked, then wifi trashed again. I'm ready to go back to Windows.

Comment: Same problem here... is it already confirmed by Apple? Any thoughts on fixing this?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. I don't know if Apple is aware of this problem. I thought they fixed it in 10.10.4 though.

Comment: Is this still a problem for you? If so, this might sound weird, but can you try this: Open a continuous ping to google.com (or any other reliable server). Then when packets start dropping, open Spotlight by using command-space.

Comment: Same problem, can barely ping router. All other connected devices work fine. Just changed the channel on my router from 11 to 7 and now wifi is working great again. (sigh)

Comment: Here's a fun trick to try:  Open a Terminal window and run this command:  "ping -i 0.1 www.google.com"  ... and see if your ping-times (as measured in another Terminal window) drop to reasonable/consistent values.  It appears that Apple's got some sort of ~200mS idle-timeout in its WiFi hardware or driver, and after ~200mS of no WiFi traffic it puts the WiFi transceiver to sleep, and then it takes a non-trivial (and non-constant) number of milliseconds to wake it up again.  Doing a 10Hz ping forces the WiFi to stay awake, and avoids that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Jeez, those ping results are terrible.

I'm on El Capitan now, but I can relate to your frustrations about the wifi. My macbook pro is a late 2012 model. I travel with my laptop and rely on it as my phone. It was a real show stopper when wifi would completely bork on the road as in not letting me connect to open SSIDs.

I made this extreme script to wipe out wifi settings and it worked for me, but it is a pain to re-enter ssid/passwords etc and for some reason the problem would show up every now and then.

For me, if wi-fi doesn't work what's the point of having a keychain? I just wanted it to work, so I was willing to wipe things out to make it so. Mac OSX will create new clandestine defaults, but obviously if you want your passwords to friend's wifi etc, backup your keychain.

You can try the script but be warned, it may not fix your problem, it may even make things worse. I do not accept responsibility for use of this script. Please look at the files and directories it is deleting.

Alternately copy and paste everything but the "#!/bin/sh" bit and run it in a terminal, I have it in script form because it was a recurring issue for me on Yosemite, the problem went away when I either upgraded or clean installed Mavericks (can't remember which I did), so I would consider upgrading your OS to Mavericks possibly. El Capitan is still painful right now with bugs and so on, but at least wifi works.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration
rm com.apple.accounts.exists.plist 
rm com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
rm com.apple.captive.probe.plist
rm com.apple.network.eapolclient.configuration.plist
rm com.apple.smb.server.plist
rm NetworkInterfaces.plist
rm preferences.plist
```