# Can I test the functioning of an AirPort antenna of a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, wifi, hardware

Recently my Wifi connection has suffered greatly on my MacBook Pro mid2012 non-retina. I now need a much stronger Wifi signal to have a working connection. I did not change my position at my desk (home and office) nor the router hardware. Other Macs have no problem at the same spot.

[image: Wifi issue]

Since the problem appeared right after the OS X 10.10.5 update and [others seem to have similar problems](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/202190/45492), **I am not sure if I am dealing with a hardware or a software issue here. Is there a way to sort that out?** I was thinking one could, for instance, measure the electrical resistance of these connectors [here](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Display+Replacement/10760#s26131):

[image]

What I tried so far:

- AppleCare stress test - no issues found
- setting DNS servers manually
- SMC & NVRAM reset
- delete `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/`

**UPDATE**

It turned out that the antenna cable in the black plastic bar on the screen was in contact with the screen's hinge. So every time I opened or closed the screen, the cable was cut a little more. This seems to be a weak design or faulty assembly in my MBP. I would still be curious how this could be diagnosed without disassembling almost the entire MacBook.

Comment: What is the name of the program on the first screenshot?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu It is a builtin OSX utility: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202663